# Play file upload form with additional fields

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

I have run into a problem with a Play 2.1.0 form that contains a file upload and an additional input field. I use

```scala
def uploadTaxonomy() = Action(parse.multipartFormData) {
    implicit request =>
      request.body.file("xml").map { file =>
        val xml = scala.io.Source.fromFile(file.ref.file).mkString
        taxonomyForm.bindFromRequest().fold(
          formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.index(formWithErrors)),
          result => {
            Taxonomies.create(result._1, xml)
            Redirect(routes.Application.index())
          }
        )
      }.getOrElse {
        Redirect(routes.Application.index())
      }
  }
```

and my form is this:

```scala
val taxonomyForm = Form(
  tuple(
    "label" -> text,
    "xml" -> text
  )
)
```

The problem is that `bindFromRequest()` always fails (causing a bad request to be returned to the client).

Does anybody have an idea where the problem might lie?

*Note:* I am aware that there is a [bug in 2.1.0](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/multipartFormData/play-framework/eWCfiI-7YFc/pzki9zRyyKUJ) that manifests when no files are selected in an upload field; it does not seem to be related, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the `xml` should not be part of the form definition as you get it directly from the request body.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! So to sum up, the solution is to use the form `val taxonomyForm = Form(single("label" -> text.verifying(nonEmpty)))`.