# file upload part map to model scala play2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

file upload code

```
request.body.file("image").map { ing =>
          val target = new java.io.File(s"./uploads/${ing.filename}")
          ing.ref.moveTo(target, true)
        }
```

How do you connect the ing.filename to the AboutImages "image" object so I can update the databases!

this is the nobel:

```
object AboutImages {

    val images = { 
        get[Long]("about_us_images.id") ~
        get[String]("about_us_images.image") ~
        get[Option[Date]]("about_us_images.created_at") ~
        get[Option[Date]]("about_us_images.updated_at") ~
        get[Option[Int]]("about_us_images.position") ~
        get[String]("about_us_images.name") map {
case id~image~created_at~updated_at~position~name => AboutImages (id, image, created_at, updated_at, position, name)
        }
    }
```

the is the form:

```
 val details: Form[AboutImages] = Form(
    mapping(
      "id" -> longNumber,
      "image" -> text,
      "created_at" -> optional(date),
      "updated_at" -> optional(date),
      "position" -> optional(number),
      "name" -> nonEmptyText
      )(AboutImages.apply)
      (AboutImages.unapply)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand your question — are you having problems accessing the form components other than the file upload?

If so, take a look at the post [Play file upload form with additional fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234550/play-file-upload-form-with-additional-fields/15236165).

Comment: hi the "image" -> text ( get[String]("about_us_images.image") ) is the file name in my database. Just trying to replace "image" with ing.filename from the form file upload.